# How to spilt a big DataFrame into Vec<DataFrame> by group in Polars

Tags: dataframe, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

I stored some financial market data in a Polars DataFrame. As for analysis, it is is fast to run some `groupby("date").agg()` action.

But in a realtime scenario , the new data is coming time by time, I don't want to concat the new data with old data again and again, it is slow and use a lot of memory. So is there a blazing fast way to spilt the old data DataFrame into small DataFrame groupby `datetime` column which stored in a vector or hashmap, so when the new data comes, I just push the new into vector for future calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Polars has a `DataFrame::partition_by` function for this.